# Flask not showing variable in html

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

So I have an HTML template that should display text within the HTML, but of course, it doesn't. My HTML is like so:

`<h2>okay {{Iputithere}}</h2>`

The flask is like so:

```
If “success” in my other function:
    Return render_template(“index.html”, headline=iputithere)
```

I’m on an iPhone.
Now, when just plain returning the variable it works fine so I know it’s not a null value. Which is what I don’t understand. The variable I am trying to return is a string but I also hardcoded a string to make sure and it still wasn’t returning in the html. Is there any reasoning?

Note: my h2 tags are not displaying I can’t fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

`<h2 >okay {{headline}}</h2 >`

You are passing the value in the `headline` variable from `render_template` so instead of `Iputithere`, you have to use `headline`